# Regex to match the last character if it is a dot

Tags: regex, openoffice-calc

In OpenOffice Calc how do I remove the last character if it is a dot?

Example:

```
dog
cat.
rabbit
```

It becomes:

```
dog
cat
rabbit
```

What regex would you use to obtain that?

Answer (score 5):

**Regular expression:**

- To match a `.`, you have to write `\.`, because `.` has a special meaning in regular expressions.
- To match the end of the line, you have to write `$`.

Putting it all together, I would use this regular expression: `\.$`. This will match a dot if it's at the end of the line. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/abPVdz/1)

**Removing the matched dots:**

1. Open *"Find & Replace"* window by pressing `Ctrl+H`
2. Type regular expression from above into *"Search for"* field, this is what you want to be replaced
3. Leave *"Replace with"* field empty, as you want to replace with *nothing*, which means it will remove the matched content (the dots)
4. Under *"More/Other options"*, turn on *"Regular expressions*"*
5. Click on *"Replace"* or *"Replace all"* button to perform the replacements

Please see [documentation](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Find_and_replace) of this Calc feature for further details.

Comment: Actually removing the period is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

> In OpenOffice Calc how do I remove the last character if it is a dot?

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1)=".";LEFT(A1;LEN(A1)-1);A1)
```